# What should I do when I have a child from zina when I am already married to someone else?

Tags: children, inheritance

I am married woman. I have a child from zina, whose father is a another person. Who should inherent the child? Who should pay for expenses? Can my husband inherit the child?

Comment: I think this link answers your question:                      http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&lang=E&Id=132410